# JS(angular) :: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried searching my answer in similar questions but without success.

I'm trying to create my first login page with Angular/PhP/MySQL. There are some great articles that helped me a lot and I got it to work finally. Al tough it works there's still 1 error in the console I can't figure out.

Console SS: (note I'm printing a console log of the variable to see what is assigned when trying to go to the home-page)
[image]

It's even pointing out where I need to look, '**application.controller.js**' on line 8. I'm printing out the console.log on line 9 which gives me a nice result (displayed above in console) so this is where I'm confused.

Here's my application.controller (partial):

```
app.run(function ($location, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService) {

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

    var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;  <<< LINE 8
    console.log(authorizedRoles);            

    if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                $location.path( "/login" );
            } else {
                $location.path( "/login" );
            }
     };

});  
});
```

'**next.data.authorizedRoles**' points to my routing file which looks like:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, USER_ROLES) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home-page-display.php',
         data: {
                authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.admin, USER_ROLES.editor, USER_ROLES.guest]
               }
    })
    .when('/login', {
         templateUrl: 'views/login.php'
    })


    .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/login'
    });

});
```

Here's part of my Factory for authentication if needed:

```
authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
    return !!Session.userId;
};

authService.isAuthorized = function (authorizedRoles) {
     if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
         authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
     }

     return (authService.isAuthenticated() && authorizedRoles.indexOf(Session.userRole) !== -1);
};
```

The login works and will redirect to my home-page but I can't get rid of this error. Since my console.log() is displaying the right user roles I'm starting to think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I suspect `$routeChangeStart` is fired twice. The property exists the first time, but doesn't the second time.

Comment: It seems it's only doing it on pages I haven't assigned any 'authorizedRoles' to in my routing. Since the login page is the only one this is the case I should change the $routeChangestart function a bit so it will only check if not '/login' or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a 'temporary' solution.

In my route file I've added:

```
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.php',
    data: {
           authorizedRoles: []
          }
})
```

Of course the $routeChangestart will not allow this page without the permission, which is none. So in the routechange function I've added:

```
&& authorizedRoles != 0
```

to prevent if from firing when there's no roles assigned.

```
if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles) && authorizedRoles != 0) {
```

There are probably way better and cleaner solutions but at least my error message is gone! :)